# How to solve "RuntimeError: CUDA error: invalid device ordinal"?

Tags: python, opencv, pytorch

I'm trying to run this code. I don't know what is wrong with it, but this code is not running. and I don't know how to solve this problem.

```
import cv2
from facial_emotion_recognition import EmotionRecognition

emotion_detector = EmotionRecognition(device='gpu', gpu_id=1)
camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    image = camera.read()[1]
    image = emotion_detector.recognise_emotion(image, return_type='BGR')
    cv2.imshow('Camera', image)

    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key == 27:
        break

camera.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

but I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/fahim/Documents/Python_projects/Python tutorials/pantech AI Master/Computer_Vision/Day 8 Face emotion recognition/emotion.py", line 4, in <module>
    emotion_detector = EmotionRecognition(device='gpu', gpu_id=1)
  File "/home/fahim/anaconda3/envs/Computer_Vision/lib/python3.7/site-packages/facial_emotion_recognition/facial_emotion_recognition.py", line 25, in __init__
    self.network = NetworkV2(in_c=1, nl=32, out_f=7).to(self.device)
  File "/home/fahim/anaconda3/envs/Computer_Vision/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 607, in to
    return self._apply(convert)
  File "/home/fahim/anaconda3/envs/Computer_Vision/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 354, in _apply
    module._apply(fn)
  File "/home/fahim/anaconda3/envs/Computer_Vision/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 354, in _apply
    module._apply(fn)
  File "/home/fahim/anaconda3/envs/Computer_Vision/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 376, in _apply
    param_applied = fn(param)
  File "/home/fahim/anaconda3/envs/Computer_Vision/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 605, in convert
    return t.to(device, dtype if t.is_floating_point() else None, non_blocking)
RuntimeError: CUDA error: invalid device ordinal

Process finished with exit code 1
```

This is my the configuration of my computer:
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce MX130
CPU: Intel i5-10210U (8) @ 4.200GHz
Help me to solve this please.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try changing:

```py
emotion_detector = EmotionRecognition(device='gpu', gpu_id=1)
```

To:

```py
emotion_detector = EmotionRecognition(device='gpu', gpu_id=0)
```

`gpu_id` is only effective when more than one GPU is detected, you only seem to have one GPU, so it throws an error since you tell the function to get GPU 2 (since we count from 0).

Comment: I tried that at first. Didn't work.
Got this error: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/fahim/anaconda3/envs/Computer_Vision/lib/python3.7/site-packages/facial_emotion_recognition/model/model.pkl'

Comment: @FahimkamalAhmed, it looks like you don't have a `model.pkl` file. You need a model in order for the recognition to work. There should be a model in the source file, if there isn't try reïnstalling the package.

Comment: @FahimkamalAhmed in that case, it did work. You just got another error that is unrelated to the original one.

Comment: @funie200 yes you were right. model.pkl files was missing from the files. I tried to reinstall the library but still the file was missing every time. So I downloaded the tar.z file from pypi.org and take the model.pkl file from there and paste that in my libraries. It's working now. It's 1 am in the morning, I must say I'm very happy with my work. Thanks man.

Comment: If your model has a config file, the device may also be set in there. In my case it was defaulted to 1, and switching to 0 got it working.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was accidentally setting `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0` and attempting to set a process to a device other than 0. To fix that, you can either run

```
unset CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES
```

or

```
export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1,2,3,4,...
```

depending on the number of GPUs you have/want to use.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not from using
`emotion_detector = EmotionRecognition(device='gpu', gpu_id=0)`
or similiar function...Try below work-around

As in my case ,it was due to presence of this line in my code

```
torch.set_default_tensor_type('torch.cuda.FloatTensor')
```